# JavaScript básico, como podría resolver el siguiente problema

Tags: javascript

Buenas tengo lo siguiente:

```
 let autos = [

 {
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Fiesta',
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    color: 'Azul',
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'APL123',
    vendido: false

},

{
    marca: 'Toyota',
    modelo: 'Corolla',
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    color: 'Blanco',
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'JJK116',
    vendido: true
}
]

let concesionaria = {
autos: autos,

buscarAuto: function(param){
}
}
```

Bueno la idea es que la funcion buscarAuto reciba una patente y me retorne el auto correspondiente en caso de no encontrarlo deberia retornar null, PD: Soy nuevo aprendiendo Javascript se que debe ser basico pero me vendria bien una ayuda y una explicacion del porque, habia pensado en un ForEach pero no sabria como implementarlo. desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Bueno la idea es que la funcion buscarAuto reciba una patente y me retorne el auto correspondiente en caso de no encontrarlo deberia retornar null

Puedes lograr esto con la funcion [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/find):

```js
const autos = [
 {
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Fiesta',
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    color: 'Azul',
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'APL123',
    vendido: false
},
{
    marca: 'Toyota',
    modelo: 'Corolla',
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    color: 'Blanco',
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'JJK116',
    vendido: true
}
];

function buscarAuto(patente){
  return autos.find(auto => auto.patente === patente) ?? null;
}
console.log(buscarAuto("JJK116"));
console.log(buscarAuto("ASDASD"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que por "retornar el auto correspondiente" te refieres a que devuelva toda la información del coche en cuestión.

Puedes hacerlo de muchas formas pero una muy directa es usar el método *findIndex*.

Este método busca en un array de objetos (por una determinada propiedad) cual de ellos tiene el valor que le pasas, y devuelve el índice del array en caso de éxito o *-1* en caso contrario.

```js
 let autos = [
 {
    marca: 'Ford',
    modelo: 'Fiesta',
    precio: 150000,
    km: 200,
    color: 'Azul',
    cuotas: 12,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'APL123',
    vendido: false
},
{
    marca: 'Toyota',
    modelo: 'Corolla',
    precio: 100000,
    km: 0,
    color: 'Blanco',
    cuotas: 14,
    anio: 2019,
    patente: 'JJK116',
    vendido: true
}
];

console.log(buscarAuto('JJK116'));

function buscarAuto(patente){
  var idx = autos.findIndex(x => x.patente == patente);
  return idx != -1 ? autos[idx] : false;
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué no usar `find` directamente? Algo como: `const buscarAuto = patente => autos.find(a => a.patente === patente) ?? null`.

Comment: @gugadev, no se me había ocurrido. Me gusta más.

Comment: En ese caso es preferible utilizar `filter` en lugar de `find` porque la primera devuelve un **Array** con las patentes que se consultan y la segunda solo devuelve un resultado.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. no veo la ventaja en utilizar filter. Find es justamente lo que necesita en este problema.